# Overriding a generic function produce an error

Tags: swift, xcode, generics

I am writing a `generic function` in a `protocol`, but an `error` occurs when `overriding` this `function` in `inherited classes`.

**The first way i use**

```
protocol BaseCellProtocol {
    associatedtype T
    func configure<T>(with object: T?)  
}

class TableViewCell: BaseTableViewCell {

    typealias T = String

    override func configure<T>(with object: T?) {
        label.text = object as? T
    }

}
```

But this way produce an `error`:

> Cannot assign value of type 'T?' to type 'String?'

`T` was `overrided` in class as `String`, but `compiler` don't understand that `T` is `String`

**The second way**

```
protocol BaseCellProtocol {
    func configure<T>(with object: T?)
}

class TableViewCell: BaseTableViewCell {

    override func configure<String>(with object: String?) {
        label.text = object
    }

}
```

In this case, the `error` is:

> Cannot assign value of type 'String?' to type 'String?'

Whaaaaat?

I am new to `generics`, I read some literature, but I have some problems with this.

**update**

```
class BaseTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, BaseCellProtocol {

    typealias T = String

    func configure<T>(with object: T?) {
    }

}
```

Comment: The code doesn't compile

Comment: So, is `BaseTableViewCell ` conforming to `BaseCellProtocol` ?

Comment: @MayRestinPeace, yes

Comment: @idev.agg.mf What is the typealias you are giving in `BaseTableViewCell` ? Can you post the code for `BaseTableViewCell` ?

Comment: is a problem because a String is a structure?

Comment: You don't need to define the function as generic, try `func configure(with object: T?)` in the protocol.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson this works, but there is no ways for use generic functions here?

Comment: But what do you want to accomplish, there is no point in making something generic without a specific reason?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I agree with You in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove `<T>` in function. Because you have T in `typealias`.

```
protocol BaseCellProtocol {
    associatedtype T
    func configure(with object: T?)
}

class BaseTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, BaseCellProtocol {

    typealias T = String

    func configure(with object: T?) {
    }
}

class TableViewCell: BaseTableViewCell {

    override func configure(with object: String?) {
        label.text = object
    }
}
```